# How to copy a text file content and convert it into lines

Tags: python, text

I am trying to make a program that is able to copy a text file and then write out another text file with the same content but changed. For example:

```
SAS- numbers
PR  - 123
SE  - 456
TE  - 789
```

The one above is the original text file, but I would like to know how can I make it so it looks like this when my program writes out the copy of the original one:

```
numbers;123;456;789
```

This is what I have for now:

```
    openfile = input('Enter the input file: ')
    outputfile = input('Enter the output file: ')

    output = open(outputfile,'w')
    with open(openfile, 'r') as inputfile:
                output.write(inputfile.read())
    output.close()
```

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: can you post your issue exaclty when you are performing this task?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath  I posted my code, the problem with it is that it just copies the text file and writes it out the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Look into my Below code. This might help you.

```
input_data = ""
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    input_data = f.readlines()

output_data = ";".join([line.split("-")[1].rstrip("\n").strip() for line in input_data])

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(output_data)
```

Comment: I think a brief explanation about the code will help him.